# how to embed value with an apostrophe in querystring

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript:

```
tr.append("<a href='add_widget.html?id=" + data[i].id + "&pg=" + data[i].page_number + "&dest=" + data[i].dest + "&name=" + data[i].name.replace("'","\\'") + "'</a><button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>");
```

The code in question has to do with the name field. 
If I have a name like "John Doe" when I click on the hyperlink created by the above javascript, the new page's querystring has the full name. 
However, if I try to pass a name like "John's stuff", the above logic creates a query string variable that looks like this:

```
&name=John\
```

How can I change the above code so that the entire string "John's stuff" is passed to the add_widget.html page?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be using `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the parameter values. *edit* (but that won't help with the quotes I guess)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, there's a much better way of doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

replace("'","%27")

try http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ it's an online URL encoder/decoder.

Comment: The built-in (and generally deprecated) `escape()` function will do this.

Comment: Using the javascript encodeURI or encoreURIComponent is the best way to get rid of unwanted URL characters.

Comment: probably better to use global replace: `replace(/'/g,"%27")`

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeGravel yes but try it - `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` will not replace single-quote characters with `%27`.

Comment: @Pointy: Right, which lead me to ask this question: is apostrophe an invalid character in an URL string?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeGravel no it's not, but it's not URI syntax that's causing problems for the OP - it's HTML syntax. If the OP were to build the `<a>` element and then use JavaScript to assign the URL to its "href" attribute, there'd be no problem.

Comment: @Pointy, I got it! The HTML is dynamic and is within a double quote, which force you to use single quote for the attribute values that in turn make usage of apostrophe problematic within the attribute's value.

Comment: @Pointy, but since the apostrophe will be within an URL if you want to get it back to an apostrophe in the receiving page or server request, %27 will do the trick while &#39; will be kept like this for the receiver (but displayed correctly in HTML).

Comment: @formix it depends on how the URL gets to the "href" property of the DOM node. In the OP, it's getting there via HTML markup, so the HTML parser will interpret the entity notation while it's *parsing* the `<a>` tag. There will be no HTML entity notation in the value of the "href" attribute after the parse is completed.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to "protect" characters, you have to keep in mind what you're protecting them from. In this case, there are two interpreters you have to worry about:

- You're building HTML, so you have to worry about the HTML parser;
- You're building a URL, so you have to worry about how the browser and the server will parse the URL.

To deal with the first problem, you can replace the quotes with the HTML entity equivalent (`&#39;`).  To deal with the second, you can use `encodeURIComponent()`.

I think you'd want to do the `encodeURIComponent()` call *first*, to avoid having the HTML entity notation get messed up. The entity notation will be gone after the HTML parser is finished with the string anyway:

```
function qEncode(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/'/g, "&#39;");
}
```

To use that:

```
tr.append("<a href='add_widget.html?id=" + 
  qEncode(data[i].id) + "&pg=" + 
  qEncode(data[i].page_number) + "&dest=" + 
  qEncode(data[i].dest) + "&name=" + 
  qEncode(data[i].name) + 
  "'</a><button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>"
);
```

Note that you could also encode double-quote characters too.

A totally different way of working around this problem would be to build the DOM content with DOM APIs. By doing that, you'd completely avoid the HTML parser, and you'd just need `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Isn't _URI encoding `%xx`_ different to _HTML Encoding `&#xx;`_ ?, i.e. will not `%xx` be ignored by the _HTML interpreter_? **edit** didn't read OP's code in full, it's in a _URI_ so it's right to encode for both

Comment: @PaulS. right - the reason the OP is having problems is that the URL is being built up as an attribute value embedded in HTML markup. The HTML parser is what's causing the problem, because it sees the single-quote character as terminating the attribute value.

Comment: sorry @Pointy can you modify your answer slightly to just give me a complete example of the two function calls that need to be made? just want to be certain that I'm on the same page

Answer (score 1):

You need to think, what will be interpreting my code, so what do I need to escape for?

1. Your code will be interpreted by the *HTML Interpreter* in the browser
2. Your code will be interpreted as a *URI*

This means you need to escape/encode them in reverse order. Luckily *JavaScript* provides a *URI* encoder as `encodeURIComponent`, but it doesn't provide a *HTML* one (probably as we have *DOM Methods*) but it isn't too hard to implement for important characters, e.g.

```
function html_encode(str) {
    var re_chars = /[<>'"]/g;
    function replacer($0) {
        return '&#' + $0.charCodeAt(0) + ';'
    }
    return str.replace(re_chars, replacer);
}
// example follows
html_encode('<foo bar="baz">'); // "&#60;foo bar=&#34;baz&#34;&#62;"
```

So for you,

```
attrib_value = html_encode(/* ... + */ encodeURIComponent(data[i].name) /* + ... */ );
```

---

For completeness,

```
function html_decode(str) {
    var re = /&(?:#\d{1,3}|amp|quot|lt|gt|nbsp);/g, // notice extra entities
        d = document.createElement('div');
    function replacer($0) {
        d.innerHTML = $0;
        return d.textContent;
    }
    return str.replace(re, replacer);
}
// and an example
html_decode('&#60;foo bar=&#34;baz&#34;&#62;'); // "<foo bar="baz">"
```

Comment: If you're wondering about `html_decode`, I'm putting these into the `<div>` match-by-match instead of all at once to avoid undesired loading or code execution (e.g. of an `<img>`)

Answer (score 0):

Using `escape(data[i].name)` instead of `data[i].name.replace("'","\\'")`, will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but seems to me like the deeper issue is that programming languages accept/use the apostrophe character (ie %27) as a single quote. 
It seems like this is a fundamental semantics issue. The apostrophe and the single quote are semantically two different things, but the same character is being used for both purposes. I encountered this issue passing surnames through query string that contain apostrophes - eg "O'Reily". The apostrophe in the surname is treated as an open single quote and it breaks the query string because it gets replaced with a double quote in HTML and then doesn't have a matching terminating double quote.
My view is that the apostrophe character should not equate to a single quote. But that is a very large issue and I guess it would be too late to change that now.

So, back to fixing this issue in a realistic way, it seems to me that the escape() method does the best job.
As others have said, `encodeURIComponent()` does not encode apostrophes. With that in mind, what is the benefit of using `encodeURIComponent()` over `escape()`?
Would it be better to do both? `encodeURIComponent(escape())`?

Comment: Does this mean that the apostrophe character was removed from the unescapedURISet in a recent ECMA update and used to be in there when escape() was the preferred method? If so, why was it removed?